# I need to return true or false in procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, boolean, return

I need help with this stored function:

1. The function should return a Boolean.
2. If row exists given a couple of parameters than return True or 1 (False or Zero).
3. Function must accept 2 parameters.

.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ( @id varchar(12), @subvarchar(12))

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = @id AND subid = @subid )
.....//return true else  ....//return false
```

I need to return true or false.

Comment: May we assume this is sql-server? If so, please can you add the `sql-server` tag.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
I would use a function (scalar, or possibly table-valued but this would require a change to a set-based approach)

[SqlFiddle of the various options here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1bf8/9):

**Details**
There is no boolean type in SQL Server - the closest is a BIT (0 / 1). Stored procedures can only return an `INT`, although it is unusual to (ab)use the return value in this way, as it is intended to indicate the success or failure of the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc( @key varchar(12), @subkey varchar(12)) AS
  RETURN (
    SELECT CASE
      WHEN exists
       (select * from contacts where [key]=@key and [subkey]=@subkey) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
      END);
```

More commonly, you would use an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyOutputParamProc( @key varchar(12), @subkey varchar(12), @result BIT OUTPUT) AS
  SET @result =
    CASE
      WHEN exists
       (select * from contacts where [key]=@key and [subkey]=@subkey) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
      END;
GO
```

Alternatively, you could `SELECT` a result, which would return a single row, single column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc( @key varchar(12), @subkey varchar(12)) AS
  SELECT CASE 
      WHEN exists
       (select * from contacts where [key]=@key and [subkey]=@subkey) 
        THEN 'true' 
        ELSE 'false'
      END AS 'Result';
```

That said, since you aren't changing data, a User Defined Function could be preferable to a PROC in this case, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc(@key varchar(12), @subkey varchar(12))
RETURNS BIT
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CASE 
      WHEN exists(select * from contacts where [key]=@key and subkey=@subkey) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
      END);
END;
```

Called like so:

```
SELECT dbo.MyFunc('key', 'subkey')
```

One last point - if you need to retrieve several keys at the same time, and if performance is important, then you might also need to consider approaching this problem in a set-based manner, e.g. by accepting a Table Valued Parameter to your proc / function.

Comment: its not worked ,gave me an error "Incorrect syntax near '1'.
"

Comment: Apologies - I had a couple of typos, notably naming of the proc / func, and [key] is a reserved word.